# Group by and Having using the same Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code for a SSRS report using stored procedures, I want to filter the group by to display only the information concerning group level 2, but I'm not sure how to do so.

Here is the stored procedure I am using:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE CheckActiveMembers 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(MemberID), GroupLevel
    FROM Member M
    INNER JOIN [Policy] P ON P.PolicyID = M.PolicyID
    INNER JOIN [Group] G ON P.GroupID = G.GroupID
    WHERE GroupLevel = '2' AND M.CancellationDate IS NULL  
    GROUP BY GroupLevel
    HAVING GroupLevel = '2'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by is used to group records and applying having works for within that specific group only on which it is applied whereas a where clause is valid for whole table itself like in your case

```
    SELECT COUNT(MemberID), 
GroupLevel
FROM Member M
INNER JOIN [Policy] P
ON P.PolicyID = M.PolicyID
INNER JOIN [Group] G
ON P.GroupID = G.GroupID
WHERE GroupLevel = '2' AND 
M.CancellationDate IS NULL  
GROUP BY GroupLevel
HAVING GroupLevel = '2'
```

The having is irrelevant here as you have already filtered records in your `where` clause having usually is used to check aggregation within that group

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING` should only contain aggregated columns, non-aggregated (grouped) columns go with `WHERE`:

```
SELECT COUNT(MemberID), GroupLevel
FROM Member M
INNER JOIN [Policy] P
ON P.PolicyID = M.PolicyID
INNER JOIN [Group] G
ON P.GroupID = G.GroupID
WHERE GroupLevel = '2' AND M.CancellationDate IS NULL  
GROUP BY GroupLevel
```

If you wanted ones where there was > 1 member, you could use the aggregated `COUNT` in the `HAVING`:

```
SELECT COUNT(MemberID), GroupLevel
FROM Member M
INNER JOIN [Policy] P
ON P.PolicyID = M.PolicyID
INNER JOIN [Group] G
ON P.GroupID = G.GroupID
WHERE GroupLevel = '2' AND M.CancellationDate IS NULL  
GROUP BY GroupLevel
HAVING COUNT(MemberId) > 1
```